# Byte-range support in Active Storage Rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, audio-streaming

I have an audio file that I'm trying to stream down. The client wants "Byte-range support" - but I can't get that to work with Active Storage:

`rails_blob_path(article.audio)`

How do I go about adding byte-range support?

EDIT

I realized that rails_blob_path is just a wrapper around the service url, so maybe that's what's causing the issue? Is there a way to get the service_url publicly? I get a `Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET`

Comment: It's not related to Active Storage. Nginx(or Apache) must serve files too client. They support byte-range.

Comment: @AlexKojin, I realized that rails_blob_path is just a wrapper around the service url, so maybe that's what's causing the issue? Is there a way to get the service_url publicly? I get a `Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET requests.`

Comment: @HappyCry did you ever figure this out? Trying to do the same for video/mp4 files